try—catch can‘t catch the exception，cause when exception happend，enter recursion in catch ，try block dont work and just into the catch block
package object.myobject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CatchTheException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    void receiveInt(){
        System.out.println("please input an int");
        try{
            System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
            System.out.println("try block wont work");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("the input is wrong, please input again");
            receiveInt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CatchTheException().receiveInt();

    }
}

I don't know why the try block wont work，maybe is the exception not catched？ I’m a newbie of the try catch. i run and try block wont work make the recursion wont stop, so i get a stackoverflow exception

You need to clear the nextline character before calling receiveInt() again

Hello usuario25443671, I don't understand why you say your code doesn't work, if I enter "p", it prints java.util.InputMismatchException, the input is wrong, please input an int and if I enter "3" it prints try block wont work, what do you expect it to print?

The question is when i print "p"  it will made the code in the receiveInt() called again and again but the code in the try block wont run  lead to the StackOverFlowException

What should i do to clear the next line chararcter in detail

Re: "what cause made the try block wont work": nextInt() is throwing an Exception because the input is not a valid int (e.g. some letters); the System.out.println(scanner.nextInt()); terminates by that Exception, without calling println(); the catch block is executed, printing "the input is wrong, please input again" and calling receiveInt() again; since the previous nextInt() did not consume the input, the same happens again: nextInt() will again throw the Exception, println(scanner.nextInt()) will be terminated without printing, catch block is executed, ...

ok, well, thank you for the comment, now i know the problem is the Exception of the scanner

You need to remove receiveInt(); in the exception.
Example:
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Please input an int");
        scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("That isn't an integer");
        scanner.next();
    }
}


Thank you very much, this is the right answer to avoid the this situation, but if you know what cause made the try block wont work, please tell me

@CodeNewbie - It's because the receiveInt() call within your code exception block will create an infinite recursion that will quickly lead to a StackOverflowError.

@CodeNewbie the issue is with "enter" key you press. It is also getting considered as a character. This causes issue.

oh, i see, thanks for your explain

@CodeNewbie if my answer solved your problem. You can accept it as solution and help others also :)

I will, if i see anyone have this sort of problem, i will try my best to help them(●'◡'●)

@CodeNewbie on stackoverflow, you mark the answer that solved your problem as accepted by clicking on the tick.

Here An Alternative way to do this sort of thing:
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String num = "";
while (num.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer value: -> ");
    num = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    /* Is the supplied value a string representation of a
       signed or unsigned integer value?     */
    if (!num.matches("-?\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry (" + num + ")! Try again...\n");
        num = ""; // Ensure re-loop
    }
}
        
// Passed entry validation:
int number = Integer.parseInt(num);  // Convert string value to Integer type:
System.out.println("Your Number: -> " + number);


Thanks for you comments, this is a good way do slove this sort of problem
